# Add value automatically to child table's foreign key column

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have
Table1 having columns Id and name and 
Table2 having column Id, c1
, I want that when I insert values into table 1 then it's id should go into c1 of table2 automatically in one transaction using LINQ. c1 in primary key with reference to Id column of Table1.
I can achieve this in two transactions by following.

```
Table1 t1 = new Table1();
t1.name="something";
con.Tables1.insertOnSubmit(t1);
con.SubmitChanges();
Table2 t2 = new Table2();                
t2.c1=t1.Id;
con.Tables2.insertOnSubmit(t2);
con.SubmitChanges();
```

But I want to do all this is one transaction, i.e. using con.SubmitChanges() only one times. I am using C# with LINQ. Please help.

Comment: are you using entityframework?

Comment: @muhammadhasnain using LINQ to SQL

Comment: @S.Akbari it was a typo i am using con.Tables2.InsertOnSubmit(t2); to insert in second table.

Comment: @S.Akbari if i skip con.SubmitChanges(); on line 4, then i get zero in t2.c1.

Comment: Seems the `Id` is identity, so you can't get `Id` before submitting data to the database, because it is generated on database.

Comment: @S.Akbari yes, I know, that's why I am looking for the solution.

Comment: `Table2` should have a reference navigation property to `Table1`, i.e. you should set `t2.Table1 = t1` instead of setting `t1.c1`. Then LINQ-to-SQL with figure out itself how to set the FK in one transaction.

Comment: @GertArnold can you tell me after which line i need to add this line?

Comment: instead of `setting t2.c1` -- made a small typo.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you so much.